# How to compress jpg and png images in java?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I used ImageIO library and tried to compress Multipart File but if the extension is jpg then it works fine, but when I used png file then it's not working.

I got this error while executing this code

```
byte[] byteArr = multipartFile.getBytes();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);

public String compressImage(MultipartFile multipartFile, BufferedImage image) throws IOException {
    String filePath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    File compressedImageFile = new File(filePath);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile.getName());
    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(FilenameUtils.getExtension(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
    ImageWriter writer = writers.next();

    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
   
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(0.5f);
    
    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
    os.close();
    ios.close();
    writer.dispose();
    return String.valueOf(compressedImageFile);
}
```

Method threw 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' exception."
stack trace

```
    ERROR TextMessaging:309 - An exception occured while executing sendMessage.json: 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Compression not supported.
    at javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.java:914) ~[?:1.8.0_301]
    at com.starbucks.amazon.services.impl.ImageCompression.compressImage(ImageCompression.java:36) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.starbucks.amazon.services.impl.ImageCompression$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9a83d3e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at com.starbucks.amazon.services.impl.ImageCompression$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87686d38.compressImage(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.starbucks.amazon.restcalls.TextMessaging.sendMessage(TextMessaging.java:222) ~[classes/:?]
```

Comment: Stack trace and code please. The connection between image I/O and [tag:spring-boot] escapes me.

Comment: Also escaping me is the connection between `ImageIO` and compression. Do you really mean compression or do you mean resizing? Attempting to compress an image without really specialized software won't give you a good ratio

Comment: @g00se Saving an image as JPEG already applies compression, according to the `q` value chosen. PNG also supports lossless data compression.

Comment: Yes I know that. My point is that methods available in Java will not produce a significant compression ratio

Comment: @g00se Why do you think Java can't produce significant compression ratio? JDK ImageIO JPEG implementation is based on libjpeg and should produce the same compression ratio.

Comment: I think we're talking at cross purposes. ANY binary file that can produce a non-lossy high compression ratio is by definition badly designed. That doesn't tend to happen. I'm just trying to avoid the OP wasting his/her time. You've even saiid yourself: *PNG format will be written compressed regardless, as PNG always use zlib/deflate compression.*

Comment: @g00se JPEG can produce extremely significant compression ratios. I don't know why you think otherwise, or why you think the OP is wasting his time. You don't know anything about his images and how well they may compress, and it is futile beyond description for you to claim they, or JPEG, are 'badly designed'.

Answer (score 2):

As seen from the stack trace, the problem is `param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT)`. This is perhaps counter-intuitive based on the fact that PNG does indeed support compression, so I fully understand the confusion. However, the API is what it is...

Change:

```
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(0.5f);
```

To:

```
if (param.canWriteCompressed()) {
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(0.5f);
}
```

PNG format will be written compressed regardless, as PNG always use zlib/deflate compression.

PS: In more recent versions of the JDK, the `PNGImageWriteParam` supports specifying the compression level ([from JDK 9](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6488522), [backport exists for JDK 7 and 8](https://github.com/gredler/jdk9-png-writer-backport)). The above code will work anyway, but it will affect the compression ratio (lower numbers means less quality/more compression). You might want to handle compressions for different formats more explicitly.